# google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 The caller does not have permission

Tags: google-cloud-platform, automl, google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-automl-nl

I have used AutoMl Vision api from gcp and trained it with my custom dataset. I'm able to get predict the data GCP console but not able to store the predicted output. For the purpose of storing the predicted data output and to use my local data for prediction I tried the python code that was given as part of API which accepts the image file content, project name and bucket name but when I try to run it is showing me the error: google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 The caller does not have permission
[cloud sdk error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHfK3.png)

Comment: How did you give storage permission?

Comment: As this is the first I am using GCP not sure what you are asking, can u please give some more information.

Comment: To write inside a bucket you must have a storage permission given to the account, either the account used by you python code or a service account used in this specific part for the upload

Comment: In addition to what @adm said
For points 5 and 6, I had to manually add the service account I had created to the list and assign the role. I think my gcloud version is a later (243.0.0)

Answer (score 15):

it is simple first the google cloud documentation is not in sync with the code:
Please follow these steps:

1) Open command prompt and fire this: `set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS= /path/to/your/credentials.json` (its best to put it in the same folder as google cloud sdk

2) `gcloud auth login` ( a webpage will be opened saying you are authenticated after you login in to your google account)

3) `gcloud config set project YOUR PROJECT_ID`

4) `gcloud auth activate-service-account YOUR SERVICE ACCOUNT@projectID.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

5) `gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding YOUR PROJECT_ID --member serviceAccount: (the service account you used in step 4)`

6)`gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding YOUR PROJECT_ID --member user: (the email you have affiliated to your gcloud account)`

7) Done.

if you do have any issues creating a service account see this video: 
[create and use service account](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tSnzoW4RlaQ)

Hope it helps :)

sources: i had the same problem

Comment: Step 4: Throws error: `ERROR: (gcloud.auth.activate-service-account) argument --key-file: Must be specified.`

Comment: to clarify, in steps 5 & 6, the member arguments are a single string, with the literal prefix shown, including the `:`, followed by the email address which identifies the service account (for step 5), or your google email as specified above for step 6.  Also, a `--role` arg was required. I used `roles/reader` for my service account, and had previously effectively granted my user account `roles/owner` through the UI.

Comment: re @yardstick17's comment i'm guessing they didn't set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env var; I had, and didn't get the given error.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue until I added "Cloud Datastore persmission" to my service account in order to access firestore data.